# Laravel Bind Class with auth user

Tags: laravel, authentication

How can I bind class with `auth user`? Here's what I've tried so far, but it's not working.

```
$this->app->bind(NotificationInterface::class, function($app){
    return new Notification(Auth::user())
});
```

Here is my Notification class

```
class Notification implements NotificationInterface
{
    use NotificationCollectTrait;

    /**
     * @var Guard
     */
    private $auth;

    /**
     * Notification constructor.
     * @param Guard $auth
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;

        if(!$this->auth->check())
            throw UnauthorizedException::notLoggedIn();

        # Setup Notifications
        $this->notifications();
    }
 ....
```

and here is my controller where i want to inject the interface

```
class Notification extends Controller{

protected $notification;

public function __construct(NotificationRepositoryInterface $notification)
{
    $this->notification = $notification;
}
...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what "isn't working" about it?

Comment: $this->app->bind(NotificationInterface::class, function($app){
           $guard = $app->make(Guard::class);
           return new Notification($guard);
});

i think i have found a solution for binding, but i don't know why not working when I try to inject in controller __construction(NotificationInterface $notification) 

authentication is false

Comment: because there is no session yet, by the time the constructor of the controller has ran the request has not gone through the middleware stack, which means no session, so no auth

Comment: how can i resolve ?

Comment: can you go into what you are going to do with this implementation of that interface in the class or constructor

Comment: Class is a bit long how can i write here in comment sorry but i am new here, maybe is a stupid question

Comment: no worries, you can edit your question to include more information ... basically just want to know what you doing/why you need to do this, not the actual code at the moment as there may be other ways to go about this

Comment: Hope now i am clearly in my question, i have update my question

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, this way is working, thanks @lagbox for trying to help me

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function($request, $next){
        $this->repository = app(NotificationInterface::class);

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

this is controller construct